# Performance difference of multiple Catch Vs Multi-Catch

Tags: java, performance, try-catch, multi-catch

I know that there are advantages and dissadvantages when using multi-catch blocks in java.

But does the multi-catch statement has any **performance** advantage over multiple single catch blocks? Does the compiler treats them differently?

Comment: I think you should talk about performance **difference**. When you say "performance advantage", people tend to mistakenly think that these kind of micro-optimizations are something you should care about.

Comment: Exception handling is pretty slow anyway, so why would anyone care about performance? If your code is throwing 1000 exceptions per second, you've got bigger problems to worry about than catching performance.